# 37signals-style layout template

Tags: html, css, 37-signals

My wording might be a bit off, but I wonder if there's an open-source HTML/CSS template/framework for creating 37signals-style layouts, much like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [basecamphq.com](http://basecamphq.com/images/screenshots/dashboard.png))</sub>

Of particular interest is the tabbed layout and the sidebar to the right.

Comment: This is only tangentally related, but I was reading this interesting article on copyright ( http://blog.pastie.org/2008/05/copyright---des.html ) and it talks about how 37signals doesn't like people using their layout, even though there is nothing actually wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all free, but still a good reference: [34 Outstanding Admin Panels for Your Web Applications](http://www.ourtuts.com/34-outstanding-admin-panels-for-your-web-applications/)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of WordPress Basecamp style themes about:

[Prologue](http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2008/01/28/introducing-prologue/)

[P2](http://p2theme.wordpress.com/)

[GTD](http://templatic.com/freethemes/gtd-%E2%80%93-private-blog-theme-for-teams-to-collaborate)

Answer (score 1):

Try some open source template sites then, most likely you'll have to get something similar and edit it.

E.g:
( http://www.oswd.org/ )

Goodluck